# How to Acknowledge mail related to PhD Proposal?

Tags: phd, thesis

I had applied for PhD Scholarship. Today i received a email from that foundation. They told me 
**"As soon as you are ready with your PhD Study Proposal, please send it to Prof X"**

How to Acknowledge this mail in formal way that i am going to send my PhD Proposal to Prof X as soon as it is ready?

Comment: Did the foundation ask for an acknowledgement? If not, there is no need to reply, imo.

Comment: They send this mail to group of people. I am not sure whether acknowledge this mail or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably go with "thank you for this opportunity for support.  I anticipate that I will be sending this document by xx/xx/xxxx"  This way, if they need it sooner, they might let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to assume that the receipt of an e-mail that has been sent to a group of people and that does not explicitly ask otherwise does not have to be acknowledged. They can be treated as an FYI.

If the sender does need a confirmation, they will get back to you.